# My Codekata solution delivers the correct solution, but runs into performance Issues during final test-cases

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I completed my algorithm in python3 to solve a "codekata" on codewars.com.(https://www.codewars.com/kata/odder-than-the-rest-1/train/python) My code solves the initial test cases correct and with sufficient speed. However, when submitting it for the final test, the code gets a timeout for taking too long to solve the given tasks.

Initially I had the content for the for-loop implemented as a separat function called "calculate_oddness_level". I found out this could be a bit slower than just doing the implemention inside the for-loop,so i just did that.

I am aware that performing a while loop inside a for loop is not optimal performance-wise. I thought about how to avoid this several times. However I need do determine the "oddness" level for every odd number in my list. For determining the "level" a loop is needed and seemed faster than a recursion. So its seems there was no other option than to run a while-loop inside the for-loop. I however eliminated all even numbers from running a loop by just assigning them "oddness-level" 0 right away.

Therefore I dont know how I could achieve any significant improvements in performance.

```
def oddest(a):
        if len(a) == 0: return None
        list_of_oddness_levels = []
        for n in a:
                if n % 2 == 0:
                     list_of_oddness_levels.append(0)
                else :
                    level = 1
                    while True:
                        n = (n-1)/2
                        if n % 2 == 0 or n % 1 != 0:
                                break
                        else:
                                level += 1
                    list_of_oddness_levels.append(level)
                print("adding Level!")
        maximum = max(list_of_oddness_levels)
        index_of_maximum = list_of_oddness_levels.index(maximum)

        if list_of_oddness_levels.count(maximum) > 1:
                return None
        else:
                return a[index_of_maximum]
```

According to the initial test-cases my code should solve the task correctly. However its seems like it runs way to slow, since it runs into a timeout-error during final submission.

I am aware, that there might be some simple mathematical solution or some 5 lines of advanced code utilizing some python3 libraries or special functions I dont know. However a "clean code" solution which is detailed, goes step by step and is descriptive as possible would be preferred.

Comment: Using [line_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/line_profiler/) on your code may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need a list, you could do it with O(1) additional space.
- It is likely that not your implementation is the problem, but **-1**. Why? It is infinitely odd, because (-1 - 1) / 2 = -1. Interestingly this is the only such number, all other negative numbers have an oddity level of 1.
- For positive numbers you are basically counting the number of consecutive bits set to 1 from the right, so you can work with masks to be even faster.

This is how such an implementation could look like, assuming 32-bit integers (sorry Java):

```
public Integer oddest(int[] a) {
    if (a == null || a.length == 0)
        return null;
    // create the 31 masks needed, the left-most bit is only set for negative numbers
    int[] masks = new int[31];
    masks[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
        masks[i] = (masks[i - 1] << 1) | 1; // masks[i - 1] * 2 + 1
    int bestNumber = 0;
    int bestLevel = 0;
    boolean conflict = true;
    for (int n : a) {
        int level = 0;
        if (n == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else if (n & 1 == 1) { // number is odd
            if (n < 0) {
                level = 1;
            } else {
                // now use the masks and bisection to find the oddity of positive numbers
                int left = 0; // finally at the index of best matching mask
                int right = 31; // never reached, finally left + 1
                while (left + 1 < right) {
                    int mid = (left + right) >> 1;
                    if (n & masks[mid] == masks[mid])
                        left = mid;
                    else
                        right = mid;
                }
                level = right;
            }
        }
        if (level > bestLevel) {
            bestNumber = n;
            bestLevel = level;
            conflict = false;
        } else if (level == bestLevel && n != bestNumber) {
            conflict = true;
        }
    }
    if (conflict)
        return null;
    return bestNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, your hints and your code example. The problem indeed turned out to be the "-1". I just solved it by assigning the oddness level of any number coming down to -1 at some point to "999". At this point the final test cases finished pretty fast.